# Existence of Maya and God

Tags: vishnu, gods, bhagavata-purana, maya, spirituality

Would God help only those who are Good or follow Dharma ( I know this is false as there are many stories in which he helped people who were under Maya ) still what I don't get is Why can't he help everyone know that the materialistic World is an illusion? Many Puranas establish the nature of the Absolute Truth, but people could only read them with his Kripa....Why can't he help the Atheists too? Why is it only "few chosen people" realize? Why can't he spread the Goodness of Bhakti? Why is it that Maya spreads so easily?

Comment: Is not that Maya spreads so easly ...

My divine energy Maya, consisting of the three modes of nature, is very difficult to overcome. But those who surrender unto Me cross over it easily.

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 7, Verse 14

Comment: basically, if you follow Maya You can't follow the Gods.

Comment: Oh Why is it God doesn't help people overcome Maya?

Comment: Because  who never searched for Moksa needs to return many times in order to understand how to overcome it.

Comment: But it also said To search for Moksha one should have Krishna's Anugraha....

Comment: @SHASHAANKB.H. there are criterias given by Bhagavan himself how to get his anugraha by giving up false ego, develop devotion,  humility, etc.

Comment: But Bhalichakravathy said that if one is good it is only because of Bhagwan's kripa and every step we take is only because of him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God doesn't normally interfere in the working of the universe and its living beings.

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
> again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
> owing to Nature's sway over them.

**Gita 9.8**

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, because **I remain detached
> like one unconcerned in their midst.**

**Gita 9.9**

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
> of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
> revolve.

**Gita 9.10**

God doesn't interfere with the lives of jivas.

Why doesn't God let everyone know that the material world is an illusion? The answer is that it is His sweet will. He wants the creation to continue.

If a Jiva wants to be an atheist then God will not make him a devotee. Why doesn't God make an atheist a devotee? It is His sweet will. He probably wants the creation to continue.

Only a few people realize God because it is very difficult to overcome maya.

> My divine Maya (power) constituted of the three Gunas is difficult to
> overcome. Whoever takes refuge in Me alone, in utter devotion,
> overcomes it.

**Gita 7.14**

Comment: So in simple terms the answer is the will of God right?.... Also it is Dharma that helps people realize God and if people do Bhakti then they benefit right?

Comment: Yes, will of God plays a very important role. Dharma keeps people on the right track. You have to do one of the four Yogas, Jnana Yoga, Karma Yoga, Bhakti Yoga and Raja Yoga  to realize God.